unconfigure and other problem - new at control
i have problem with ros2 control:
yamel file
# Controller Manager Parameters
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 1000  # Set the update rate to 1000 Hz
    use_sim_time: true

# Joint State Broadcaster Configuration
joint_state_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
    type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

# Position Controller Configuration
position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
    joints:
      - back_left_joint
      - back_right_joint
      - front_left_joint
      - front_right_joint
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

# Velocity Controller Configuration
velocity_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
    joints:
      - back_left_joint
      - back_right_joint
      - front_left_joint
      - front_right_joint
    command_interfaces:
      - velocity
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity


launch 1
import os
from pathlib import Path
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, SetEnvironmentVariable, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue

def generate_launch_description():
    # Define package directories
    x8_sim_dir = get_package_share_directory("x8_sim")
    gazebo_ros_pkg = get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros')

    # Declare the model argument to specify the path to the URDF file
    model_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name="model",
        default_value=str(Path(x8_sim_dir) / "urdf" / "robot.urdf.xacro"),
        description="Absolute path to robot URDF file"
    )

    # Use xacro to process the URDF file and load the robot description parameter
    robot_description = ParameterValue(
        Command(["xacro ", LaunchConfiguration("model")]),  # Ensure proper command usage
        value_type=str
    )

    # Node to publish the robot state
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}],
        output="screen"
    )

    # Set the environment variable for Gazebo model path (updated for model directory)
    gazebo_resource_path = SetEnvironmentVariable(
        name="GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH",
        value=str(Path(x8_sim_dir) / "models")  # Updated to point to the models directory
    )

    # Include the Gazebo server launch file
    start_gazebo_server_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            str(Path(gazebo_ros_pkg) / 'launch' / 'gazebo.launch.py')
        ),
        launch_arguments={'world': LaunchConfiguration('world')}.items()
    )

    # Spawn the robot in Gazebo using the robot_description
    spawn_robot = Node(
        package="gazebo_ros",
        executable="spawn_entity.py",
        arguments=["-topic", "/robot_description", "-entity", "x8_robot"],
        output="screen"
    )

    # Declare the world file argument
    declare_world_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name='world',
        default_value=str(Path('/home/naor/Desktop/naor/work/x8_c++/src/x8_sim/worlds/obstacle.world')),
        description='Path to the Gazebo world file'
    )

    # Return the complete LaunchDescription
    return LaunchDescription([
        declare_world_cmd,
        model_arg,
        robot_state_publisher,
        gazebo_resource_path,
        start_gazebo_server_cmd,
        spawn_robot
    ])

this launch is work fine - the problem with the secend launch of the control:
this the problem launhc :
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import TimerAction
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    # Path to the YAML configuration file
    yaml_config_path = os.path.join(
        os.getenv('HOME'), 'Desktop/naor/work/x8_c++/src/x8_sim/config/controllers.yaml'
    )

    # Gazebo Controller Manager Node
    controller_manager = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='ros2_control_node',
        parameters=[yaml_config_path],
        output='screen'
    )

    # Define the controller spawners with delays
    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = TimerAction(
        period=5.0,  # 5-second delay for joint state broadcaster
        actions=[Node(
            package="controller_manager",
            executable="spawner",
            arguments=[
                "joint_state_broadcaster",
                "--controller-manager",
                "/controller_manager",
                "-p",
                yaml_config_path
            ],
            output="screen"
        )]
    )

    position_controller = TimerAction(
        period=10.0,  # 10-second delay for position controller
        actions=[Node(
            package="controller_manager",
            executable="spawner",
            arguments=[
                "position_controller",
                "--controller-manager",
                "/controller_manager",
                "-p",
                yaml_config_path
            ],
            output="screen"
        )]
    )

    velocity_controller = TimerAction(
        period=15.0,  # 15-second delay for velocity controller
        actions=[Node(
            package="controller_manager",
            executable="spawner",
            arguments=[
                "velocity_controller",
                "--controller-manager",
                "/controller_manager",
                "-p",
                yaml_config_path
            ],
            output="screen"
        )]
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        controller_manager,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        position_controller,
        velocity_controller
    ])

thanks for the help

please give more context. what do you want to do with the second launch file? Spawn additional controllers to your gazebo model?
